# How to use NuGet targets in standalone MSBuild script without separate call to Restore target

Tags: msbuild, nuget-package-restore

I'm invoking an MSBuild script that isn't a `csproj` from a bat script. I would like that script to be able to use the [MSBuild Community Tasks](https://github.com/loresoft/msbuildtasks), and I don't want to have to install it on every machine, nor do I want to include its binaries in my repo.

By adding these nodes to the script and calling the `restore` target, the package restores.

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="MSBuildTasks">
    <Version>1.*</Version>
  </PackageReference>
</ItemGroup>
```

To use the tasks it contains, I only need to use them. I don't need to import any other `targets` files:

```
<Target Name="MyTarget" DependsOnTargets="Restore">
    <AssemblyInfo CodeLanguage="CS"
                  OutputFile="$(VersionInfoFile)"
                  AssemblyVersion="1.2.3.5"
                  />
</Target>
```

However, the first time I run my script, the package restores, but then the script fails because it can't find the `AssemblyInfo` task. The second time, it succeeds. Is there any way to get this to work without calling the MSBuild script twice (the first time, specifically running the `Restore` target)?

Answer (score 2):

You can force a re-evaluation of the imports generated by NuGet by calling the msbuild file from itself using the `<MSBuild>` task with a different set of global properties (!).

```
<Target Name="MyTarget" DependsOnTargets="Restore">
    <MSBuild Projects="$(MSBuildProject)" Targets="MyTargetCore" Properties="Foo=Bar" />
</Target>

<Target Name="MyTargetCore">
    <AssemblyInfo CodeLanguage="CS"
                  OutputFile="$(VersionInfoFile)"
                  AssemblyVersion="1.2.3.5"
                  />
</Target>
```

Depending on the circumstances (solution build, project references), it may or may not work without the `Properties="Foo=Bar"` part.

However, note that this is a bit risky since not all msbuild caches can even be cleared using the arguments on the `MSBuild` task. MSBuild 15.5 is going to add a `/restore` switch that will execute the `Restore` target, clear all necessary caches and then do the other requested work. So in 15.5 you should be able to call `msbuild /restore /t:MyTarget` without any difficulties.